# Do edits count to 40 minute asking limit?

Tags: support, rate-limiting

I have asked question yesterday this morning I have slightly edited it and when I tried to ask on different SO site I got

> You can only post once every 40 minutes.

**Is this ok? Or am I missing something?**

Comment: Do you share your ip address?

Comment: @PatrickHofman I work in corp so probably I do, I think this answers the mystery..... Should I delete the question or it's worth leaving it for other (idiots) like myself?

Comment: Maybe that is the issue, maybe not. One of the employees could give a definitive answer. I would keep it for now.

Comment: This rate limit is network wide. So if you asked a question *anywhere* on the network, you won't be able to ask again for 40 minutes on any sites where you have less than 125 reputation.

Comment: @animuson I had only one question network-wide that morning...